# Read GATT characteristic values using Java

Tags: java, bluetooth, sensors, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to read GATT characteristic values from a Bluetooth LE sensor (Texas Instruments CC2541) using Java (Java SE, not Android!).

So far, I'm managed to get the COM port serial communications working, but can't figure out the best way to read GATT values. I see some complex-looking docs describing the protocols and the exact bytes to be sent / received but I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this using an existing library / API?

What is the recommended way to read the GATT values? A code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I managed to hack something together that worked using Clojure.... still it's not a very comprehensive solution, so I'm still keen to find out if anyone has a better library/approach! https://github.com/mikera/motion-sensor

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278993/android-ble-how-to-read-multiple-characteristics ?