# Android How to read BLE properties Readable Writable Notifiable GATT Characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics

How to read `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` properties like is characteristic `Readable`, `Writable` or `Notifiable`.

Answer (score 16):

```
    /**
     * @return Returns <b>true</b> if property is writable
     */
    public static boolean isCharacteristicWritable(BluetoothGattCharacteristic pChar) {
        return (pChar.getProperties() & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) != 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns <b>true</b> if property is Readable
     */
    public static boolean isCharacteristicReadable(BluetoothGattCharacteristic pChar) {
        return ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) != 0);
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns <b>true</b> if property is supports notification
     */
    public boolean isCharacteristicNotifiable(BluetoothGattCharacteristic pChar) {
        return (pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0;
    }
```

Comment: I really do not know why, but in Android official sample is
" if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) "
Using '&' is in my opinion correct, but ' | ' is working for me. Anyway, could you explain, why this BluetoothGattCharacteristic properties have values which they have? For example 0x02 for PROPERTY_READ. In any service Read is my first property.

Comment: These are service address, you have different address for each service running on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar problem where the sample code ONLY works when the characteristic is READ because of the operator "|". If the characteritic is of other types such as Notification or Write, the code will always set it sup as READ. The correct code should be as the following:

```
if((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0){ 

} else if(charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFICATION) > 0){
}
```

(...Continue with other cases)

Again, the google sample code is NOT correct.

David

Comment: You mean "charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFICATION", right?