# How can I connect two android phones?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I want to connect two android phones via Bluetooth low energy but, I dont know how to create characteristic uuids and service uuid in android; I Googled a lot that I could connect the two android phones via Bluetooth low energy but, could not find useful stuff.

Please guide me that how could I solve the issue. I would be very thankful for this act of kindness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making an application that will connect the devices? (in that case: add some code or info on what you already have, or want to acchieve) Or are you just asking in general how you can do that, eg. what application you could use? (in that case, statckoverflow isn't the right place for that question)

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood:

- Upload BluetoothChat sample codes to both devices using Eclipse or Android studio
- Pair them
- Open BluetoothChat sample app
- Connect to each other

Bingo, you are connected and even can chat in a range.

Regards

Comment: I want to exchange data b/w the phones using BLE characteristics uuids which is introduce in api-18(Android 4.3). BluetoothChat sample does not full fill my requirements.

Comment: So please be more specific, friend. Check these links [BLE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html), [Writing to a Characteristic using the Android 4.3 API](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/1423/writing-to-a-characteristic-using-the-android-43-api/), [BLE how to read multiple Characteristics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278993/android-ble-how-to-read-multiple-characteristics).

Comment: Dear my problem is not writing/reading to/from characteristic uuid. I want how to make android phone as peripheral that could scan it with other android phones. No doc exists in the developer site in this regard. I want to know is there any other way to do this.