# Android Gatt: how to know to which request a response belongs?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

Short question:
When `BluetoothLECallbackInterface.onCharacteristicRead()` is triggered, how do I know which request this is an answer to?

A bit more detailed:
when calling `BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()`, the `onCharacteristicRead()` method of the `BluetoothGattCallback` object I passed when connecting the device will be called
(the one I passed to `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()` )

Now let's imagine I'm making ten different readCharacteristic() calls.
`onCharacteristicRead()` will be triggered 10 times.
How can I know which callback-call belongs to which request?
How or when or to which class/method could I pass a request ID, when calling `readCharacteristic()`, on which I could rely in `onCharacteristicRead()` to identify the request I'm just being handling the result?

I'm just discovering bluetooth connection and communication, maybe my question makes no sense, maybe I'm supposed to be waiting for a request to be finished before I start calling a new request?
But when using asynchronous calls, I assume I can make all the calls I want to, then  sort out the responses, because *something in the response* tells me which request it is an answer to.
This ***"something in the response"*** is what I can't find anywhere in android documentation.
The contrary would be like having to wait the delivery confirmation of an email before being able to send a new one, without risking not to know which one was delivered... :-(

A scenario maybe more convincing with writing characteristics.
Imagine I want to give a bluetooth device some values he then has to store, sum or whatever, device-side.
I send 1, 3, 4, 2 and 7 to this device.
Let's say `onCharacteristicWrite()` is triggered 4 times with success and one time with failure status.
How can I know which request hasn't been taken in account device-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simultaneous reads or writes are not supported. You need to wait for a callback before starting next request. A typical implementation uses a Queue to simplify it.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358451/1860868

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. Especially this answer made it clear for me, why it is async when it has to be used sequencially: "They probably did it because sending a read-request to another device in synchronous execution would mean you cannot do anything with your app until an answer is received. By making it Async you can do other stuff, but no other bluetooth requests." https://stackoverflow.com/a/38740652/3872061